# How to dynamically find a value of a key-value in json in bash script

Tags: bash, json, jq

I'm new to bash scripting. I am iterating over a list and want to get the value from a JSON object. I've tried all 3 of these and am getting a `jq: 1 compile error`

What is the proper syntax?

```
for key in $KEYS
  echo "ALIASES:" $ALIASES
  # ALIASES: {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'bananna'}

FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq ."$key" -r)
FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq .'$key' -r)
FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq .$key -r)
```

Comment: It's unclear what the exact values of `$ALIASES` and `$KEYS` are.  Given the JSON in the code, that should generate a `parse error: Invalid numeric literal` message, unless the value in `$key` is not a valid JSON key.

Comment: I may also want to know why you are using a shell loop over the keys of the JSON document instead of performing that loop in `jq` directly. This would probably only involve a single invocation of `jq` instead of starting `jq` once for each key.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seems to be in your json data because you have:

```
{'a': 'apple', 'b', 'bananna'}
```

As far as I know using single quotes is not valid (use double quotes): [json format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).
The another problem I see is that you have a comma `,` between `'b'` and `'bannana'` (I assume you didn't notice that and you typed `,` instead of `:`)

So Your json data should be like this:

```json
{"a": "apple", "b": "bananna"}
```

**What is the proper syntax to get a key?**

I usually see that the syntax `'.key'` is more used. However I think you should use any which works. For example, I see in your case that you are using a variable `$key` to get specific value from a json key. So, you should use something like `".$key"` or maybe `."$key"`, `.$key` (I'm not sure if these are recommended):

**Solution 1**

```bash
FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq ".$key" -r)
#or
FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq ."$key" -r)
#or
FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq .$key -r)
```

If you use or want to use `single quotes` then you will not be able to pass any variable value to `jq` command. According to `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash

Therefore If you want to use `single quotes` to a json value by specifying some key you should use:

```
FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq '.somekey' -r)
#e.g.
FRUIT=$(echo $ALIASES | jq '.a' -r)
echo $FRUIT
#Output:
apple
```

You can check [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for a better understanding about `single quotes` and `double quotes`

**Solution 2 (using jq --arg)**
I'm not sure why the code above doesn't work for you (using the double quotes). However there is another possible solution to pass variables to `jq`, you can try:

```bash
val="a"
echo $ALIASES | jq --arg key "$val" '.[$key]' -r
```

---

As you are using python to get the json then you should use the method `json.dumps(your_json)`, for example:

```bash
python3 -c 'import json;aliases = json.load(open("file"));print(json.dumps(aliases))'
```

Comment: I wouldn't have picked up on that. Thanks Edgar.  So I'm going from JSON to python to BASH. The JSON is well formed, and the python I'm doing ALIASES=`python3 -c '

import json
aliases = json.load(open("file"))]
print(aliases)
'`. In Python, I lose the double quotes.

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana If you want to change the `'` to `"` you can use these commands:
`python3 -c 'import json;aliases = json.load(open("file"));print(aliases)' | sed "s/'/\"/g" `
or
`python3 -c 'import json;aliases = json.load(open("file"));print(aliases) ' | tr "'" '"'`.
But you might have problems with the keys-values because if you have something like this: `"a": "'app'le",` the single quotes in `'app'` will be replaced by `"app"`.

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana I've updated the answer to provide a better solution to get the JSON using the python code.

Comment: That took care of the double quoting issue. I tried the 3 approaches above to access the value in bash, and in each case I get `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FORMAT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana Are you on macOS? I'm using Linux and bash/zsh and that works. I will update the answer to provide another solution!